# Can a "pre premeasure" be extended to a $\lambda$-system?

Tags: measure-theory

[Caratheodory's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) says given a premeasure on an algebra $\mathcal{E}$, one can extend the premeasure to the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{E}$. Furthermore under some conditions the extension is unique. Can the same be done for $\lambda$-systems?

Suppose $m$ is defined on $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(E)$ and $m(E) < \infty$. It is possible to show if $m_1,m_2$ are two extensions from $\mathcal{E}$ to $\lambda(\mathcal{E})$ then they must be equal ([this blog](https://almostsuremath.com/2019/10/06/the-monotone-class-theorem/) mentions it), but does an extension exist?

It seems possible because for $A \subset B \in \mathcal{E}$ we know $m(B\backslash A) = m(B) - m(A)$, for disjoint $A$ and $B$, $m(A \cup B) = m(A) + m(B)$, and for $A_0 \subset A_1 \subset \cdots$
$$
m(\cup_i A_i) = \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} m(A_i)
$$
These are the closure conditions for being a lambda system, so one might expect $m$ can be constructed inductively to $\lambda(\mathcal{E})$, but it isn't clear if the process terminates.